# Flutter: I'm working in a flutter application which i clone it from git hub, the build is failed when i trying to run it

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, version

- note that this errros is appear when i try to run an application that i clone it from github, and i don't know how to solve it

```
../../flutterVerson/flutter_windows_1.22.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-3.13.6/lib/src/form_builder_custom_field.dart:96:40: Error: The getter 'autovalidate' isn't defined for the class 'FormField<T>'.
 - 'FormField' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/form.dart' ('../../flutterVerson/flutter_windows_1.22.4-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'autovalidate'.
        autovalidate: widget.formField.autovalidate,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\mohy\flutter\flutterVerson\flutter_windows_1.22.4-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\mohy\flutter\flutterVerson\flutter_windows_1.22.4-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: The problem with projects from other authors is just that, their environment is not the same with your current environment, mainly by old versions. I recommend you clone that project but not running it, use it as reference and create your project from scratch, you'll learn more, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The below line is actually causing a problem

```
Error: The getter 'autovalidate' isn't defined for the class 'FormField<T>'
```

So, I would suggest checking all file who has form and check their autovalidate property.

once you find autovalidate property you can do the following:

1. if autovalidate has value assign as variable e.g. autovalidate:
   _variable replace it with true or false
2. Or you can remove autovalidate property from form.

> But, note that autovalidate has @deprecated from a newer version of
> flutter you need to use autovalidateMode property which takes enum
> value e.g. autovalidateMode :AutovalidateMode.always

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is using an old interface.  Modern API descriptions say:

```
@Deprecated('Use autoValidateMode parameter which provides more specific ' 'behavior related to auto validation. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v1.19.0.') bool autovalidate: false
```

You'll need to either downgrade your flutter (not recommended personally) or (recommended) fork the project and fix it and issue a pull request (to help others).

Edit: See the autoValidateMode param: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/autovalidateMode.html